# Solution of differential equation as x tends to infinity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been asked to show that each solution of the following equation remains bounded as x tends to infinity.

$d^2y/dx^2 + e^xy=0$

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

We have the ODE
$$y''+e^xy=0.$$
Multiplying by $2e^{-x}y'$ we obtain
$$2e^{-x}y''y'+2yy'=0\Rightarrow e^{-x}[(y')^2]'+(y^2)'=0.$$
Integrating from $0$ to $x$ in the variable, we obtain
$$\int_0^xe^{-s}[(y'(s))^2]'ds+\int_0^x[(y(s))^2]'ds=0.$$
Thus,
$$y^2(x)+e^{-x}y'(x)^2+\int_{0}^xe^{-s}[y'(s)]^2ds=y(0)^2+y'(0)^2.$$
Noting $\int_{0}^xe^{-s}[y'(s)]^2ds\geq0$ for all $x\geq0$, we have
$$y^2+e^{-x}(y')^2\leq y(0)^2+y'(0)^2.$$

Finally, from the previous inequality we can conclude $|y|$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

The solution containes the Bessel function:
$$y(x)=c_1 J_0\left(2 \sqrt{e^x}\right)+2 c_2 Y_0\left(2
   \sqrt{e^x}\right)$$

Comment: nice $2c_2=C$......